# Sum of digits in C++

Tags: c++, sum-of-digits

program asked is sum of digits :

***Input data are in the following format:***
first line contains N - the number of values to process;
and then N lines will follow describing the values for which sum of digits should be calculated by 3 integers A B C;
for each case you need to multiply A by B and add C (i.e. A * B + C) - then calculate sum of digits of the result.

***Answer*** should have N results, also separated by spaces

MY CODE IN C++ :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n, a, b, c, t, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        t = a * b + c;
    
        while (t % 10 != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + t % 10;
            t = t / 10;
        }

        while (t % 10 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum;
            t = t / 10;
        }
    }
    
    cout << " ";
    cout << sum;
    cout << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm having hard time correcting my code.

Any help is appreciated.

My assumption is there should be a better way to code this other than using 2 while loops.

PS : I checked other topics just want somebody that could help with my code thank you.

Comment: What is your second loop doing?  `sum = sum;` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Hint: your condition should be `t > 0`

Comment: `sum = 0; while (t) { sum += t % 10; t /= 10; }` Also, please use a debugger when unsure what’s going on. Also, printing out the `sum` *outside* the `for`-cycle doesn’t really help.

Comment: What is your question? Use CodeReview if you want someone to review your code!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need second `while` loop, and first one should be corrected to `while (t != 0)`. After that your program for computing sum works correctly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBRT8MgFIXf@RXHGZN2xbiq21yo/S@MsUnS0qZc4sOy316Bxs5GHg7hO/eeC6i@f1aNtJdxfDRWNf6kUZnO0aBlWzPmnbEXWNlq10ul4egkGDOW0EpjkeXsyhBWJJZDchw5FAdxON/iExuRfBWK6xo2nhI4dwOy2GVSUdiq4MIURZ78KfZPq4xyjKLE7FFollgHXvzi2fv@Mo1GRngIA/IZ34Pjmi4ZtQhhTyg3YuHHAYSXBb@xu06P6zyhqrDCSixAyBX/KxIZNPnBxu@5sXEsWfn6hvftDvuPww8)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n, a, b, c, t, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        t = a * b + c;
    
        while (t != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + t % 10;
            t = t / 10;
        }
    }
    
    cout << " ";
    cout << sum;
    cout << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
123 456 789
```

Output:

```
33
```

---

Just noticed that you need `N` separate outputs instead of single sum (like you did), so then your program becomes like this:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NboMwEITvfoppqkpQXDWQf0F5F8dxUkuwIGyrh4pnp7YjQfFhV/5mZ2dl33/IRtBjml41ycbdFCrdGTso0daMOaPpARKtMr2QCsbeSsY0WbRCE5KU/TL4FwhxCI4rh@SwHMa1@MK2jLr0w3UNCr8I7t2AJLh0HPKt8ip0lqVRf679ZxWhXEOR5axZbxZ49zwLeOar7Jn@fOtGIbF48Vo64yVqsYaa@fVvyLflSg@RFp8rPi7JsnMWVRUX@LbB5jk2LqcMyrqBwnUjm6aC5cUO@8MRp/OF7Yocx8Mel/PpDw)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n, a, b, c, t, sum = 0;
    cin >> n;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        t = a * b + c;

        sum = 0;
    
        while (t != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + t % 10;
            t = t / 10;
        }

        cout << sum << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2
123 456 789
321 654 987
```

Output:

```
33 15
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    
     {
    
        int num = 0;
    
        cout << "please input any number  3digits = ";
    
        cin >> num;
    
        int sum[] = { 0,0,0 };
    
        sum[0] = num/100;
    
        sum[1] = (num/10)%10;
    
        sum[2] = num%10;
    
        int x = sum[0] + sum[1]  + sum[2] ;
    
        cout << x << endl;
    
        return 0;

}
```